# Required is Treated as ConcurrencyCheck

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

When deleting an entity with a [Required] association, this association's value is also sent in the DELETE SQL statement, as if it were a [ConcurrencyCheck]:

```
exec sp_executesql N'delete [dbo].[Project] where ((([ProjectId] = @0) and ([Customer_CustomerId] = @1))',N'@0 int,@1 int',@0=1,@1=1
```

Why was this decision taken? It seems to me that it doesn't make sense.
This effectively prevents deleting detached entities by id, when we don't know the keys of all the required associations.